# How to call a method of a javascript object inside ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object

Given this code,

```
var submit = {
  send:function (form_id) {
    var url = $(form_id).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: $(form_id).serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
        this.ret(result.message);
      },
      error: function(result) {
        // Some error message
      }
    });
  },

  ret:function (result) {
    this.result_data = result;
  },

  result_data:""
};
```

will send a data from the form to a controller which if will return a json

```
$result['message'] = validation_errors();
echo json_encode($result);
```

I try to call this javascript object in this code,

```
var res = submit.send(form_id);
```

wherein `form_id` is the form `id`, and look for the output using

```
console.log(res);
```

In the console, it shows `undefined`. After searching for an explaination using google and stackoverflow itself I got the idea that,

```
this.ret(result.message);
```

is being called inside ajax which is another object, indicating that it's not part of it's method.

My problem is, how to call the method `ret()` inside ajax?

Is anyone can explain it to me?

Comment: Yes but it return undefined when looking using console

Comment: @ brett dewoody: Is this possible, it needs a function, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is several ways to deal with it.

One is ES5 compatible (and this is actually quite common pattern):

```
var submit = {
send: function (form_id) {
  var url = $(form_id).attr("action");
  var self = this; // << this is binded to self varialble
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $(form_id).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
      self.ret(result.message); // << replaced this to self so it has all the methods from the submit object.
    },
    error: function(result) {
      // Some error message
    }
  });
},

ret:function (result) {
  this.result_data = result;
},

result_data:""
};
```

And another is using arrow function from ES2015 plus deferred object returned by `$.ajax`:

```
var submit = {
send: function (form_id) {
  var url = $(form_id).attr("action");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $(form_id).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .then((result) => {
    this.ret(result.message); // << arrow function is called in context of the parent function, so no needs to change anything.
  })
  .fail(function(result) {
    // Some error message
  });
},

ret:function (result) {
  this.result_data = result;
},

result_data:""
};
```

Explanation: context of `this` in callback function will be bind to global scope not to the object's one. So you need somehow to change it.

You can actually match and mix these two methods.

You can also use `bind` or put success as a object method. As it mentioned in other answers. Same thing, you want to keep `this` to be object's context.

[There](http://javascript.info/tutorial/this) is a good article about `this` in javascript.

Comment: Not exactly the specific solution to my problem because whenever I try to look at the result on the console, I don't know why still keep returning `undefined` but using your idea I come up another solution. Thanks. The rest of the answer works also. Great!

Answer (score 2):

You've two options.

### 1. The "bind()" method (recommended)

The method `bind` is for changing the context of a function. From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Here the `bind` will change the context of success function with the reference of `this` i.e. the `submit`.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: $(form_id).serialize(),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(result) {
    this.ret(result.message);
  }.bind(this),                  // <== bind method
  error: function(result) {
    // Some error message
  }
});
```

That `.bind(this)` can also be written as `.bind(submit)`;

### 2. Using the scope variable

Since you already have access to the `submit` variable, why not directly call with `submit` instead of `this`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: $(form_id).serialize(),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(result) {
    submit.ret(result.message);
  }.bind(this),
  error: function(result) {
    // Some error message
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function(result) {
    this.ret(result.message);
}
```

In the above block the `this` refers to the function you are operating in.
To use `ret` method you should use it `submit.ret`.

Answer (score 1):

In the submit define

```
self = this
```

And then use `ret()` with `self`: `self.ret()`

Answer (score 1):

I have a small code fragment, that simulates this:

```
var submit = {
  send:function (form_id) {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function()
    { 
      console.log('send', this);
      self.ret('message'); //will do
      //submit.ret('message'); //will do
        //this.ret('message'); this.ret is not a function
      //ret('message'); ret is not defined
    }, 0);    
  },

  ret:function (result) {
    console.log('ret', result, this)
    this.result_data = result;
  },

  result_data:""
};
```

There you can see your possible choices to handle this.

Or use this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/syqjwk2q/#&togetherjs=mpwEnNDeIJ